# How to use Key.Down to navigate items across ListViews

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

My scenario as below:

```
<ListView ItemsSource={Binding TestList}>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Expander Header="{Binding Key, BindingMode=OneWay}">
                <Expander.Content>
                    <ListView ItemsSource={Binding Value}>
                        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType = {ListViewItem}>
                                <Setter Property = "IsSelected" Value={Binding IsSelected}/>
                            </Style>
                        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    </ListView>
                </Expander.Content>
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

TestList:

```
Dictionary<string,ObservableCollection<Test>> TestList;
```

Test:

```
class Test : NotificationObject
{
    public string Name { get; set;}

    private bool isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        if( value != isSelected )
        {
            isSelected = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsSelected");
        }
    }
}
```

The inner ListView SelectionMode is Single, I can use keyboard up and down buttons to navigate items in the ListView. Is there a way to implement this scenario: When the focus is on the last item of a ListView, press down key, the focus is on the first item of the next ListView; when the focus is on the first item of a ListView, press up key, the focus is on the last item of the previous ListView.

Anyone can help?

**Solution**

```
public static List<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            List<T> list = new List<T>();
            if (depObj != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
                {
                    DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                    if (child != null && child is T)
                    {
                        list.Add((T)child);
                    }

                    List<T> childItems = FindVisualChildren<T>(child);
                    if (childItems != null && childItems.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in childItems)
                        {
                            list.Add(item);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return list;
        }

        private void ListView_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            ListView currentListView = sender as ListView;

            List<ListView> listviews = FindVisualChildren<ListView>(ModulesListView);

            int currentListViewIndex = listviews.IndexOf(currentListView);

            // If the press key is Down and the selected item is the last one
            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Down)&& currentListView.SelectedIndex + 1 == currentListView.Items.Count)
            {               
                if (currentListViewIndex + 1 < listviews.Count)
                {
                    // Get next ListView
                    var nextListView = listviews.ElementAt(currentListViewIndex + 1);

                    if (nextListView.Items != null && nextListView.Items.Count > 0)
                    {
                        ListViewItem item = nextListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0) as ListViewItem;
                        item.Focus();
                        item.IsSelected = true;
                        e.Handled = true;
                    }
                }


            }
            else if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Up)&& currentListView.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                if (currentListViewIndex > 0)
                {
                    var previousListView = listviews.ElementAt(currentListViewIndex - 1);

                    if (previousListView.Items != null && previousListView.Items.Count > 0)
                    {                                              
                        ListViewItem item = previousListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(previousListView.Items.Count - 1) as ListViewItem;
                        item.Focus();
                        item.IsSelected = true;
                        e.Handled = true;
                    }
                }

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem has been solved! I have paste the solution below the question, I hope it could help other members who has the same demand, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, I tried to solve it by attached properties

using attached you can implement attachable behavior which are difficult to implement in xaml

here is what you need

xaml

```xml
<Grid xmlns:l="clr-namespace:CSharpWPF">
    <ListView l:NavigationHelper.IsEnabled="True">
        <sys:String>item 1</sys:String>
        <sys:String>item 2</sys:String>
        <sys:String>item 3</sys:String>
        <sys:String>item 4</sys:String>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Expander Header="{Binding}">
                    <Expander.Content>
                        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                                  l:NavigationHelper.IsEnabled="True">
                            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                    <Setter Property="IsSelected"
                                            Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
                                </Style>
                            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        </ListView>
                    </Expander.Content>
                </Expander>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

I have attached a property `l:NavigationHelper.IsEnabled="True"` to my list views in order to enable the behavior

NavigationHelper.cs

```cs
namespace CSharpWPF
{
    public class NavigationHelper : DependencyObject
    {
        public static bool GetIsEnabled(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsEnabledProperty);
        }

        public static void SetIsEnabled(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(IsEnabledProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsEnabled.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEnabledProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsEnabled", typeof(bool), typeof(NavigationHelper), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnIsEnabledChanged));

        private static void OnIsEnabledChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Selector selector = d as Selector;
            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
                selector.PreviewKeyDown += selector_PreviewKeyDown;
            else
                selector.PreviewKeyDown -= selector_PreviewKeyDown;

        }

        static void selector_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            Selector selector = sender as Selector;
            if (selector.Items.Count == 0)
                return;
            ListViewItem itemToSelect = null;
            if (e.Key == Key.Up && selector.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                itemToSelect = selector.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(selector.Items.Count - 1) as ListViewItem;
            }
            else if (e.Key == Key.Down && selector.SelectedIndex == selector.Items.Count - 1)
            {
                itemToSelect = selector.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0) as ListViewItem;
            }
            if (itemToSelect != null)
            {
                selector.SelectedItem = itemToSelect;
                itemToSelect.Focus();
                e.Handled = true;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

in this class I have created an attached property and attached `PreviewKeyDown` when enabled

and in the event handler I am checking if the up key is pressed and the selection is on top then choose the last item and select it and move focus

same with the bottom most item and key is down and choose the first item in this case.

and most important mark the event consumed by setting `e.Handled = true` so listview does not process it further.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! With your solution, when the focus at the last item of the first ListView, press Down button, the focus will on the first item of the first ListView, I want to focus on the first item of the second ListView, not a loop selection.

Comment: you mean that you want the focus within inner list views so after last element of first list view the first element of next list view should be focused? I think I was confused because of outer and inner list views. let me try to get the same for you.

Comment: great find!, i had something similar in mind. but this looks great. happy coding :)